# How to defend yourself in horrible conditions?

Tags: self-defense, self-training

I am at a library posting this. I live in a rough neighborhood, and, frankly, the cops can't do much about it. I rarely get enough to eat and I am regularly beat against a wall by some guys in spiked masks. I have begged them to stop, and they never kill me or cripple me, but I end up with dozens of bruises on my body. There is no martial arts gym and no self defense instruction anywhere. I am currently far away from there (I had to be because there is no library there) but if I do not return then the gangs will kill my wife and children (all women and children must stay at the "dog-house" when the man goes away). The conditions there are muddy and there are rats everywhere. The attacks are always unexpected, they normally have guns/bat/knives, and they are bigger than me (plus there are normally 50 of them). Running away is not an option, I have no guns/weapons, and they seem experienced (no martial arts, but refined). How do I fight this?

Answer (score 5):

No martial arts training will prepare you to fight unarmed against multiple armed opponents.

Your basic options:

1. Move somewhere else.
2. Collective action. You need a functioning government that takes public safety concerns seriously.